# Simple Javascript client-side form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Goodmorning everyone,

I have a problem with a script for validating a form.
Given that the module has server-side validation in PHP, what I want to achieve, too, is client-side validation.

This validation is very simple.

When you click on the SUBMIT button, you must check if all the mandatory fields have been filled in.

If they are not:

- must add a class to the input to make it change color;
- must change the content of the icon next to the input field.

I use this script which works with regards to check and class on input. However, it uses a check on the NAME of the fields.

HTML

```
<form id="signinform" method="post" action="" class="wp-user-form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();" novalidate>
  <div class="msc-login-form-input">
    <input type="text" name="log" value="" size="20" id="user_login" placeholder="Username o Email" autocomplete="off" required onkeyup="validateElement(this)"/>
    <span id="errorsign"></span> </div>
  <div class="msc-login-form-input">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" value="" size="20" id="user_pass" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required onkeyup="validateElement(this)"/>
    <span id="errorsign"></span> </div>
  <div class="msc-login-form-input-sendh">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-login" name="submit-login" value="" class="user-submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script lang="javascript">
function validateMyForm(){
    let isFormValid = true;
    let elems = document.getElementsByName("namefield");
    for(let i=0; i< elems.length; i++)
    {
        let elem = elems[i];
        if(elem.value.length < 1)
        {
            if(isFormValid){
                isFormValid = false;
            }
        } 
        validateElement(elem);
    }
    if(isFormValid)
    {
        document.getElementById("signinform").submit();
        return true;
    }
}
    function validateElement(elem){
        if(elem.value.length < 1)
        {
            elem.className = "errorClass";
        }else{
            elem.className = "okClass";
        }   
    }
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.msc-login-form-input input.okClass {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #3F4254;
}
.msc-login-form-input input.errorClass {
    background-color: #4d40ff;
    color: #ffffff;    
}
.msc-login-form-input #errorsign {
    width: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    min-height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}
.msc-login-form-input #errorsign::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f100";
}
.msc-login-form-input #errorsign.fail::before {
  content: "\f00d";
    color:#4d40ff;
}
.msc-login-form-input #errorsign.okay::before {
  content: "\f00c";
    color:#FF1493;
}
</style>
```

### The problem is that the NAMEs of my fields are not the same and therefore that loop cannot work.

How can I solve without duplicating the loop for each form field?

How can I also add the control on the class of the icon next to it?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use the builtin [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute? If that doesn't work for you add an additional `class="tobevalidated"` to each input you want to validate and use `document.getElementsByClassName("tobevalidated")` instead

Comment: Hi, I don't want to use classic validation or browser side validation.
Anyway, an excellent suggestion is to work on the additional class and not on the name.

Thank you.

Now we only need to understand how to manage the icons in the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the builtin validation, I'd do it as follows

```
let formvalid = true;
//these are the divs surrounding your elements to be validated
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("msc-login-form-input")
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  //this is the input to be validated
  let input = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

  //this is the span element holding the icon
  let icon = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

  let valid = validateElement(input);

  //set the classes input and span according to the validation result
  input.classList.Add(valid ? "okClass" :"errorClass");
  span.classList.Add(valid ? "okay" :"fail");
  input.classList.Remove(valid ? "errorClass": "okClass");
  span.classList.Remove(valid ? "fail" : "okay" );

  //the form is only valid if ALL elements are valid
  formvalid &= valid;
}


function validateElement(element) {
  if (input.value.length === 0) return false;
  //any other validations you want to do

  return true;
}
```

Furhtermore you have a problem in your DOM tree. You have mutliple `<span>` elements with the same `id="errorsign"`. That's not gonna work, because an `id` has to be unique. So remove the `id`s and grab the `<spans>` from their parents as shown above.

You could also just add the "okay" and "fail" to the surrounding `<div>` and adapt your css accordingly. Ie something like the following CSS

```
.msc-login-form-input.okay input {
  ...
}

.msc-login-form-input.fail input {
  ...
}

.msc-login-form-input.okay span::before {
  ...
}

.msc-login-form-input.fail span::before {
  ...
}
```

And the following JS

```
let formvalid = true;
//these are the divs surrounding your elements to be validated
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("msc-login-form-input")
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  //this is the input to be validated
  let input = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  let valid = validateElement(input);
  element.classList.Add(valid ? "okay" : "fail");
  element.classList.Remove(valid ? "fail": "okay");
  formvalid &= valid;
}
```

Comment: You are right as to how it lines the span IDs, in fact I am trying to use CLASS.

As for your suggestions:
_ I cannot use INPUT because the check must be done only on some fields and not on all the inputs of the form (checkbox, radio, hidden etc: no.)

Comment: Hello, do you have any other suggestions or scripts to show me?
Thanks.

Comment: TBH my suggestion is to either use built-in validation (it's quite powerfull nowadays) or use validation of your frontend-framework (you have a framework, don't you?)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but if I had wanted to use that I would have ... don't you think? :-)

I want and have to customize this validation as I suggested it to you.

In any case, thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, your current example doesn't show anything that the builtin validation isn't capable of. Furthermore the code I have shown you is perfectly capable of doing any customization you want. Just modify `validateElement` accordingly. And if you have inputs that need to be validated and others that don't need to be validated, use differnt classnames. You are talking very much about specific requirements, yet your examples fail to address or display any of those requirements ...

Comment: For this I need a developer and for this I write here.
Thank you.